# Properly Including C library (by source) in Golang project

Tags: go, cgo

Currently, I have the following source tree:

```
client
|
|--cryptlib
|  |
|  |--cryptlib.so
|  |--cryptlib.a
|  |--<C sources>
|  |--Makefile
|
|--impl1
|  |--<C sources>
|  |--impl1.go
|  |--impl1_test.go
|
|--impl2
|  |--<C sources>
|  |--impl2.go
|  |--impl1_test.go
|
|--client.go
|--client_test.go
```

The `cryptlib` library is used by both `impl1` and `impl2` and thus, both `impl1.go` and `impl2.go` start with the following `cgo` block:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I. -I${SRCDIR}/../cryptlib -L${SRCDIR}/../cryptlib -lcryptlib -Ofast 
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../cryptlib -lcryptlib
*/
import "C"
```

And this works while trying to test `impl1_test.go` and `impl2_test.go`.

However, when trying to run the tests situated in `client_test.go`, I keep getting errors claiming that the `cryptlib` library could not be found. I think this may have to do with the fact that `${SRCDIR}` in this case is `./client` which makes the rest of the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` paths incorrect (`./client/../cryptolib`).

Although it leads to repetition, I have also tried including `cryptlib` into `impl1` and `impl2`. This approach again causes issues when trying to test `client_test.go` since the combined binary now sees multiple instances of the same functions defined in `cryptlib`.

How should I properly structure my source tree and `cgo` flags such that all my `.go` source files can find my `cryptlib` library and compile?

Answer (score 0):

From the cgo Godocs:

> When the cgo directives are parsed, any occurrence of the string
>   ${SRCDIR} will be replaced by the absolute path to the directory
>   containing the source file.

So for `client_test` the `SRCDIR` is a directory level higher and therefor its CGO directives should look like this:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I. -I${SRCDIR}/cryptlib -L${SRCDIR}/cryptlib -lcryptlib -Ofast 
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/cryptlib -lcryptlib
*/
```

As far as another approach, what I normally do is install the C library in the system library directory `/usr/lib/`. That way i do not need to worry about relative references and can just use `-lcryptlib`.